# Returning an exception after using a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, keyerror

My function is passed a dictionary (of a name and a score) and a name. It then compares the name to see if its in the dictionary, and if it is, it prints the name and score.

```
def display_marks_for(adict,name):
try:
    for key in adict:
        if name == key:
            print(name,"=",adict[key])
except KeyError:
    print(name,'not on list')
```

My code prints the right thing if the name is in the dictionary but if the name doesn't exist, it doesn't print anything?

I want it to say that the name is not on the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wont get a `keyError` if you are iterating through the keys in the dictionary, because they will all be there. You might be best using an `else` statement if the `key` doesn't match `name`

```
def display_marks_for(adict,name):
    if name in adict.keys():
        print(name,"=",adict[name])
    else:
        print(name,'not on list')
```

Or if you do want to use `KeyError` exception, don't iterate through your dictionaries keys:

```
def display_marks_for(adict,name):
    try:
        print(name,"=",adict[name]) #Will Raise KeyError if does not exist
    except KeyError:
        print(name,'not on list')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to the following, as you do not need to loop through all the keys (that's the whole point of a dictionary - avoid looping to find something):

```
def display_marks_for(adict, name):
   mark = adict.get(name)
   if mark:
      print('{}={}'.format(name, mark))
   else:
      print('{} is not in the dictionary'.format(name))
```

The `get()` method of dictionaries tries to find a value for the given key, and if it doesn't exist - instead of raising KeyError, it returns `None`.

If you wanted to practice capturing the `KeyError`, you can modify your method thus - note again you don't need a loop:

```
def display_marks_for(adict, name):
    try:
        mark = adict[name]
        print('{}={}'.format(name, mark))
    except KeyError:
        print('{} is not in the dictionary'.format(name))
```